# Access current user credentials in CRM 2011 on-demand workflow

Tags: c#, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, credentials, workflow-activity

When a user runs an on-demand workflow in Microsoft CRM 2011, is it possible to access their credentials?

I am creating a custom workflow activity designed to access a sharepoint server with shared Active Directory accounts.  I would like to be able to use the user who runs the on-demand workflow's credentials for Sharepoint authentication.  Is it possible to access these credentials in custom code?  If so, how (C# if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is possible to get the credentials but you won't be able to use them to authenticate to the Sharepoint Server, at least in the online versions.

We had a similar scenario but in the end we had to use a special user to do all the work in sharepoint, we were triggering the code with a plugin and using the REST Endpoint to do the work.

You can access the the User Credentials from the localContext, but you won't be able to retrieve the password.

Is your environment onpremise or online?/

Comment: Our environment's on-premise.  Right now we've swapped the Async Workflow Service with a different AD account (which has access to SP), but we were hoping for a more "elegant" solution.

Comment: Hi Scott, 
I know what you mean ;) 
I have tried to find the same elegant solution but I couldn't. The only option that you may have could be the last answer in this post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19662/how-to-set-up-single-sign-on-for-sharepoint-integration-in-crm-2011 

That could be a solution for you as you are using on-premise environments, however you may need to use a plugin as workflows are in sandbox mode.

I couldn't try the Single Sign on myself as I am using online for both SP and CRM and the authentication doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please share your code, how did you got `NetworkCredentials` object from `CodeActivityContext`?